# empty() then run the rest of the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some json that's loaded into **li.ui-state-default** pending user entry.

The user can then enter a new entry. I want it to empty **li.ui-state-default** every time a new entry is loaded but it seems to just stay empty.

```
//data for DOM
var timeout = '';
$('.call-json').keyup(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var val = this.value;
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.ui-state-default').empty();
        $.getJSON('json/' + val + '.json', function (data) {
            // load data

            var items = [];
            for (key in data[0].attributes) {
                if (key.match('.stat.prop.type')) {
                    items.push(data[0].attributes[key])
                }
            };

            displaySortLabel(items, "type-details");

        function displaySortLabel(items, parentClass) {
                $('<span/>', {
                    'class': 'el-data',
                    html: items.join('')
                }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('.' + parentClass + ' .sort-label');
            }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you ever append anything to `ui-state-default` again

Comment: added the extra code that shows how it is appended.

Comment: I still don't see `ui-state-default` anywhere except when you empty it

Comment: `ui-state-default` is just a class that all the divs have in common. I want to empty all divs so the new content can be brought in via the json user entry. So on `keyup` the divs empty and then it runs the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending to `li.ui-state-default` by using `.appendTo('.' + parentClass + ' .sort-label')` will not work as it searches for a `.sort-label` to be present inside that `parentClass` variable.

Make sure you have the correct selector while trying to append.

Furthermore, you don't need to `hide()` and `fadeIn()`:

```
$('<span/>', {
    'class': 'el-data',
    html: items.join(''),
    'css': {
        'display': none
    }        
}).fadeIn().appendTo('.' + parentClass + ' .sort-label');
```

Comment: That is not the problem, your selector for appending seems to be wrong.